# Как можно сгруппировать пиксели за интенсивностью свечения в 16 груп

Tags: matlab

Есть изображение нужно сделать описанное выше действие, я только начал разбираться в  Matlabе, все что нашел схожего это построение гистограммы

```
imhist(image)
```

подскажите каким способом можно решить мою проблему или дайте направление на соответствующую документацию.
Спасибо

Comment: Давайте вы расскажете понятнее, в чем заключается проблема, а мы уж попытаемся помочь.

Comment: @Эникейщик Задание именно в том что сгруппировать пиксели в группы по заданной интенсивности, но единственное что я нашел это как вывести максимальную и минимальную интенсивности, гистограмму всех интенсивностей. По сути мне нужна эта же гистограмма в скалярном виде при заданных значения, простите если не понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: при построении гистограммы [можно указать количество столбцов, на которые распределяются данные](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html#buiynvy-8).  Если я правильно понял проблему.

Comment: @Эникейщик Это да, но меня интересует можно ли вытащить из самой гистограммы значения.

Comment: вот тут вроде есть решение https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/232315-grouping-data-by-value

Comment: @Эникейщик Спасибо большое